# error:java package xxx does not exist despite IDEA being aware of them

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm leanring springboot with some source code.Recent days,when I begin learning new lessons and want to import the example project I found I fail to import all the packages when I open the example project. Although previous example projects works fine.

It's especially strange that the editor actually can identify those packages - it even offered me the appropriate classes when I manually deleted the import statements, I can see the library in the Project tree under External Libraries,I even can skip to see where the package is through ctrl+click. However, I always get a list of "java: package ... does not exist" upon compilation.How should I solve the problem?Thanks!!

I hava tried following solutions:

1. reimport in maven settings
2. invalidate and restart

3.check pom.xml

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.neo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-file-upload</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

some of the wrong import

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
```

error messages while compiling:

fail to import all the packages

therefore can't resolve all the related symbols

Comment: Are you able to build with Maven? What happens when ou start a Maven install? Which versions of Java, Maven and IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: I have only tried to build with IntelliJ before...According to instruction,I hava just deleted all the contents in my  maven repository.In the command prompt,after change the directory to the folder that have pom.xml ,"mvn clean"instruction works fine,"mvn build" shows build failure.."Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project spring-boot-file-upload: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?"

Comment: I have install both java 11 and java 1.8 ,mavan 3.6.1,IntelliJ ultimate 2019.2

Comment: In the IntelliJ terminal I clean and install successful,and I found jars in the repository directory I set,but when I try to build project in the IntelliJ still the same....emmmm

Comment: What do you see in the project settings? In "Library", do you see Maven libraries?

Comment: In the project settings, go to SDKs. What is your JDK home path?

Comment: In File -> Settings, go to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner. In JRE, select "Use Project JDK".

Comment: Yes,in project settings I can see lots of Maven libraries,"classes"are white but all the "source" and "JavaDocs" are red. My JDK home path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2.I checked that  "Use Project JDK" is already selected.(no matter the problem be solved or not ,thank you for wasting time to help dealing with my question first :)

Comment: Can you see the libraries you mention in you pom.xml in the Libraries of your project setting?

Answer (score 0):

Your project is missing some dependencies. You are not only using Spring Boot, but also Spring Web and Spring MVC.

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You may want to adapt depending on the Spring version you are using.

Comment: I clean the setting files of IntelliJ then import project ,now no problem...I  think maybe the key is in the first ,I should import project instead of opening the project...(anyway Thank you for your answer!)